# Timestamps to display with AM or PM

Tags: mysql, database, time

I store articles in a mysql database with their corresponding timestamps.

I would like to format the timestamps using the date(), and display whether it's AM or PM when the article is retrieved from the database. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: Which database? What client (if so) are you using to read and write to/from the database?

Comment: it's a mysql database. no am using the usual sql queries. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you need to use date_format():

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(hour_column, '%r');
```

This gives you a 12 hour formatted time (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM), anyway also have a look at the relvant bits of the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

*Based on some of your other questions, you use PHP.*

As described on the [PHP Date page](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can use `a` (am/pm) or `A` (AM/PM) to get what you want:

```php
$showDate = date("Y-m-d h:iA", strtotime("2013-01-19 15:42:00"));
//string(18) "2013-01-19 03:42PM"
```